# How to do a get request to a route and retrieve information from an API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to do a get/query request from Angular using `$resource` to a specified route which will ping an API and then I should get an object with the results coming from the API.

This is a search function. See the flow of this issue:

Angular service:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
  .factory('Search', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/shows/:_search');
  });
```

Ctrl:

```
$scope.$watch('searchStr', function (tmpStr)
{
  if (!tmpStr || tmpStr.length == 0)
    return 0;


    // if searchStr is still the same..
    // go ahead and retrieve the data
    if (tmpStr === $scope.searchStr) {   
      Search.query({'search': $scope.searchStr})
      .$promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.responseData = data;
      })
    }
});
```

View:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="searchStr">

<textarea> {{responseData}} </textarea>
```

Nodejs:

```
app.get('api/shows/:search', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req, res);
  request.get('http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=' + req.params.search, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(error, response, body);
  });
});
```

there is what I need, I need to do a get request to `'api/shows/:search'` and do something in order to get the results from `http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=' + req.params.search` but I am still struggling how it should be done. The `search` param is the string coming from Angular in order to go to the `thetvdb` and return what I need.

Here is an example of what it should be return in case that you are sending the string param with the word "all": http://www.thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=all&language=en

Any suggestions?

Comment: does `req.params.search` contain a value?

Comment: @chresse I don't know why but I am trying to do a console.log in Nodejs I don't see anything in the terminal.

Comment: @chresse I just send 'all' word and all I see in the terminal is this: GET /api/shows?search=all 200 109.559 ms - 2806780

Comment: and also, do you think it should be a get ??? maybe a post, don't you think? @chresse

Comment: a GET should be the right method.

Comment: what happens if you access your route directly in your browser. for example `api/shows/yourSearchTerm`

Comment: I did it with Postman and it is returning just what I need now, but now I am getting an error in the browser console: `$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object` @chresse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at least your nodejs route has to return the string in the response:

```
app.get('api/shows/:search', function(req, res, next) {
  request.get('http://thetvdb.com/api/GetSeries.php?seriesname=' + req.params.search, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(error, response, body);
    res.end(body);
  });
});
```